# Sencha Touch - How to make panels accessible from an URL

Tags: controller, routes, sencha-touch-2

From this example http://www.senchafiddle.com/#dPZn0

This displays a first panel, then a second one... using a `NavigationView` component

I would like to be able to access the dynamically created panels from their URL, similarly to kitchensink or toustyle ST examples.

As an example **localhost/navViewroutes/index.html#view2**, would redirect me to the **panel2**.

You will need to download and run this fiddle locally, else you will not get the URL of panels, but the fiddle one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Controller routes. [Sencha Docs - Controller](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-routes)